# Heatmap returning error: 'x' must be a numeric matrix, but x is a numeric matrix

Tags: r, error-handling, heatmap, numeric, data-science

I am trying to create a heatmap of species abundances across six sites.
I have a matrix of sites vs species, of numeric abundance data.

However when I run my code, R returns an error that my matrix is non-numeric.
Can anyone figure this one out? I am stumped.

Exported dataframe link: [log_mean_wide](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18HtSE-Z8o6c5ZZHfry5IpbZyzjAm8sxc/view)

Working:

```
lrc <- rainbow(nrow(log_mean_wide), start = 0, end = .3)
lcc <- rainbow(ncol(log_mean_wide), start = 0, end = .3)


logmap <- heatmap(log_mean_wide, col = cm.colors(256), scale = "column", 
               RowSideColors = lrc, ColSideColors = lcc, margins = c(5, 10),
               xlab = "species", ylab = "Site", 
               main = "heatmap(<Auckland Council MCI data 1999, habitat:bank>, ..., scale = \"column\")")
```

> error message: Error in heatmap(log_mean_wide, Rowv = NA, Colv = NA, col = cm.colors(256), : 'x' must be a numeric matrix

```
log_heatmap <- heatmap(log_mean_wide, Rowv=NA, Colv=NA, col = cm.colors(256), scale="column", margins=c(5,10)) #same error

is.numeric(log_mean_wide) #[1] FALSE
is.character(log_mean_wide) #[1] FALSE
is.factor(log_mean_wide) #[1] FALSE
is.logical(log_mean_wide) #[1] FALSE
is.integer(log_mean_wide) #[1] FALSE
```

?!?!

```
dims <- dim(log_mean_wide)
log_mean_matrix <- as.numeric(log_mean_wide) 
dim(log_mean_matrix) <- dims
```

> Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

str(log_mean_wide) shows species as numeric, site as character- why does this not work then?

```
storage.mode(log_mean_wide) <- "numeric"
```

> Error in storage.mode(log_mean_wide) <- "numeric" : (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues:

1. The first column `log_mean_wide$Site` is non-numeric.
2. `heatmap` only accepts a `matrix` as input data (not a `data.frame`).

To address these issues, you can do the following (mind you, there is *a lot* of clutter in the heatmap):

```
# Store Site information as rownames
df <- log_mean_wide;
rownames(df) <- log_mean_wide[, 1];

# Remove non-numeric column
df <- df[, -1];

# Use as.matrix to convert data.frame to matrix
logmap <- heatmap(
    as.matrix(df),
    col = cm.colors(256),
    scale = "column",
    margins = c(5, 10),
    xlab = "species", ylab = "Site",
    main = "heatmap(<Auckland Council MCI data 1999, habitat:bank>, ..., scale = \"column\")")
```

[image]

Comment: This is great thank you. I had a feeling it would turn out scrappy as there are so many species.. back to the drawing board. It was a matrix initially but I exported it as a dataframe. 
When I run this code I get the error message: 
Setting row names on a tibble is deprecated.Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = value) : 
  invalid 'row.names' length 
Did you get this? Am unsure how to resolve.

Comment: @chloep No I don't see that error. You must have some additional code that causes this, since in my solution I'm not working with `tibble`s or any `tidyverse` functions. I just downloaded and read your data as `log_mean_wide <- read.csv("log_mean_wide.csv")`.

Comment: @chloep PS Regarding the clutter: Perhaps filter for columns (species) where `colMeans` exceeds some threshold? You can see that there is a big white area where values are essentially all zero. Or define some column ranking metric by which you select the top 10 species?

Comment: Yes that will be a good approach- will tackle that once can get around this tibble issue! Will update with my code once have succeeded..

Comment: @chloep Good luck;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but since I spent some time figuring out what the issue was, I will add an answer here. Drawing a `heatmap`, specifically adding an  annotation column may fail if the annotation data is a `tibble`.

Reproducible example:

```
test = matrix(rnorm(200), 20, 10)
test[1:10, seq(1, 10, 2)] = test[1:10, seq(1, 10, 2)] + 3
test[11:20, seq(2, 10, 2)] = test[11:20, seq(2, 10, 2)] + 2
test[15:20, seq(2, 10, 2)] = test[15:20, seq(2, 10, 2)] + 4
colnames(test) = paste("Test", 1:10, sep = "")
rownames(test) = paste("Gene", 1:20, sep = "")
annotation_col = data.frame(
  CellType = factor(rep(c("CT1", "CT2"), 5)), 
  Time = 1:5
)
rownames(annotation_col) = paste("Test", 1:10, sep = "")
pheatmap::pheatmap(test, annotation_col = 
                     annotation_col)
```

The above works. However, if you instead were using a tibble, you would get an error

```
pheatmap::pheatmap(test, annotation_col = 
                     dplyr::as_tibble(annotation_col))
```

> Error in cut.default(a, breaks = 100) : 'x' must be numeric

**NOTE**

I think it would have been better for this error to specify that we needed a `data.frame` instead of something else. That might have been more specific.

See [this](https://github.com/raivokolde/pheatmap/issues/86) issue.